# Synchronize the size of two wpf controls in both ways

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, size

So I have multiple controls of which I want to have the size synchronized in both directions, meaning their size can change and the synchronized controls should get the maximum size. Eventhough these elements are laying in grids I can't use the `SharedGroupSize` because its to many elements (looks funny how WPF is adjusting the gridsize, but I stopped it after 15 minutes and not even being half through - or is there a trick to make this faster?)

Now making one element follow the size of another is easy (bind `Width/Height`to `ActualWidht/Height` but I can't figure out how to do it in both directions (using the maximum).

Comment: maybe you just bind all of them to a same properties of your ViewModel?

Comment: @vasily.sib hm, not sure how you envision that. I mean, I can't make a size property in my view model since it doesn't know how big the view should be (thats the job of wpf).

Comment: It's true, that this will violate MVVM View-ViewModel separation principle. But what I'm truying to point you to, is that you can establish a two-way binding of `Width/Height` of all elements to something common. i.e. a DataContext that holds your ViewModel, **or** your custom class instance (which implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`) initialized as control resource

Comment: The separation is not the problem, the problem is that the VM really don't know which size it should be. Lets say I hookup `ActualHeight/Width` of my widgets, take the max, bind that to corresponding `Width/Height`properties of the widgets. That works exactly once, after that the actualsize will not change as I told wpf with my binding that it should have exactly that size. Okay so lets say If I take the max of the `DesiredSize` and set `Width/Height` to that, my widgets wont stretch anymore to the space they should take.

Comment: I mean thats the problem that is causing the many many layout passes when I use `SharedGroupSize` ... I was just wondering if there is a method that isn't involving writing custom controls which explicitly handle the measure and arrange steps of wpf.

Comment: Ok, I will post an answer with example, so you can see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

One way to achive this is to bind all `Width/Height` properties to a same ViewModel property. Here is an example:

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int width, height;

    public int Width { get { return width; } set { width = value; RisePropertyChanged(); } }

    public int Height { get { return height; } set { height = value; RisePropertyChanged(); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

View:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    <!-- ... -->
    Height="{Binding Height, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
    Width="{Binding Width, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="10,10,0,0" Height="{Binding Height}" Width="{Binding Width}"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="300,10,0,0" Height="{Binding Height}" Width="{Binding Width}"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="10,180,0,0" Height="{Binding Height}" Width="{Binding Width}"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="300,90,0,0" Height="{Binding Height}" Width="{Binding Width}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

View code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Now buttons size will be tracked as your form size, including form resizing. I will repeat, this is not a perfect solution, but this may lead you to one.

Comment: But now you have in essence bound the button sizes to the size of the window (over the viewmodel).

Comment: Sorry, didn't know it would sent on enter. Thank you, but its really not what I'm looking for. Maybe there is a misunderstanding of what I want to achieve. You have in essence bound the button sizes to the size of the window (over the viewmodel). I want to that the widgets determine their size themselves and then they should synchronize that they have the max size. Your approach takes completely away that the buttons determine their size themselves (as will all approaches that bind something to `Width`and `Height`).

Comment: After thinking more about it, I think it really can't be done, without causing the same problems that `SharedGridSize` brings with it. The problem is, that the actual size of the widgets is only known, after WPF has done its arrange layout pass, thats the moment where then the size of the other (in case of two widgets) has to be updated, causing another layout pass...